# ios Javascript history.go(-1) not work for Safari in ios 10.2.1

Tags: javascript, php, ios, safari

I use php to check email format and use Javascript to alert but I use history.go(-1) it redirect in url/undefined

this is my code

```
if (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$message = "Email format not true";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');window.location = history.go(-1); </script>";
}
```

thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location = history.go(-1);
```

Is wrong. It should be:

```
window.history.go(-1);
```